# Finding the Co-Factor matrix

Tags: c

I wrote a program to find a cofactor matrix for an particular element of the given matrix. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the no of rows and columns:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int A[n][n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("\nEnter the (%d,%d) element:",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
        }
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       {

        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf(" %d",A[i][j]);
            
        }
        printf("\n");
       }    
    int B[20][20],k=0,l=0,a=0,b=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       if(i!=a)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(j!=b)
                {
                    B[k][l]=A[i][j];
                    l++;
                }
            }
        k++;
        }
        
    }
    n--;
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf(" %d",B[i][j]);
            
        }
        printf("\n");
        }
}
```

Now here I have declared the element as (0,0) and have tried to find its co-factor matrix but it is giving me junk values after the first output line. Please correct the programme.

Comment: sample input missing

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to reinitialize `l` after the first row. Change

```
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
```

to

```
            for (int l=0, j=0; j<n; j++)
```